# Algolia laravel Noun issue

Tags: algolia

I have a tag named web design. Then i searched for web designing. Since it is a Typos 3 it will not show tag named web design. Is there any way in algolia to list designers,designing etc words in just design tag

Answer (score 0):

Tags in Algolia are considered as facets/filters. It's a way to filter a set of results to only keep the one that have some specific tags applied to them. Those filters are configured through the `attributesForFaceting` option, and when you use them you have to use the exact name (so, `web design` in your case).

On the other hand, Algolia also allows you to search in a more free form, by searching for keywords in your record. When doing so, the search is typo-tolerant, meaning you can search for `web desnign` and still find results. The fields that can  be searchable are defined by the `searchableAttributes` option.

Note that you can combine both if you want. You can have free form search for `foo` and out of this results only keep those that have a tag of `bar`. It will find records with the word `food` but not those with a tag of `bart`.

In your case it seems that what you want it the free form search and not the filtering.